# How to update slider value programatically in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I have a pricing slider bar in jQuery 1.4.5 where I want to update the min/max values upon load. Somehow this does not change the values at all

// part of json:

```
"stats":{"price_min":5990,"price_max":26419}}
```

// slider:

```
<label for="filter_price">Preis:</label>
<div data-role="rangeslider" id="filter_price" style="touch-action: none;">
    <input type="range" name="price_from" id="price_from" min="0" max="20000" step="100" value="<?=$filter_val['price_from']?>" data-popup-enabled="true">
    <input type="range" name="price_to" id="price_to" min="0" max="20000" step="100" value="<?=$filter_val['price_to']?>" data-popup-enabled="true">
</div>
```

[image]

// jquery:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('stats')  && obj.stats && obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_min')) {
  $('#price_from').slider("option", "min", obj.stats.price_min);
  $('#price_to').slider("option", "min", obj.stats.price_min);  
}          
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('stats')  && obj.stats && obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_max')) {
  $('#price_from').slider("option", "max", obj.stats.price_max);  
  $('#price_to').slider("option", "max", obj.stats.price_max);  
}
$('#price_from').slider("refresh", true);
$('#price_to').slider("refresh", true);
```

How can I change the values of min / max after I get the json min/max values, even if the html code has been rendered and there is a fallback min/max value hardcoded in html?

Answer (score 0):

Get the HTML node using JQ and store it to a variable.
Using that variable change the attribute you wish to change.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Please let me know if you wish to see a better example, and I will write one.